# Pandas & Jango - How to create a DataFrame filter from multiple user inputs without using string executable

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am building a website where users can graph data in a dataframe and apply filters to this data to only plot information they are interested in, as shown below

[image]

Right now I am having trouble figuring out a way to take the filters a user inputs in the fields above and using those inputs to filter the dataframe. Since the user can create an unbounded number of filters, I decided to use a for loop to build an executable string that contains all of the filters in one variable that is shown below

```
column = (value selected in "Select Parameter", which corresponds to a column in the dataframe)
boolean = (value selected in "Select Condition" e.g., >, <, >= ect....
user_input = (value user inputs into field e.g., 2019 and Diabetes)

executable = 'df = df[df[' + column1 + '] ' + boolean1 + user_input1 + ' and ' + 'df[' + column2 + '] ' + boolean2 + user_input2 + ' and '.....
exec(executable)
```

While this method works, it leaves my code very vulnerable to injection. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I suggest creating a dictionary to map the inputs from users to operations in pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module, it has operators as function. You can do `operator.lt(a,b)` for `a<b`. Just map user input to an operator.

ex:

```
import operator
operator_map = {'<':operator.lt, '<=':operator.le, '>':operator.gt}
```

Then you can create a filter like

```
import numpy as np

# Start with selecting all then `and` the filters
df_filter = np.ones((df.shape[0],),dtype=bool)

# Go through each user filter input
for ...:
    df_filter = df_filter & operator_map[boolean](df[column], user_input)


filtered_df = df[df_filter]
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Regarding the operator module, is there an operator equivalent to "a !in b". It looks like it only has an operator to check if  "a in b"

Comment: There isn't for `not in`, but you can create one using `not` operator and `in` operator. 
```not_in = lambda a,b: operator.not_(operator.contains(a,b))``` and use it like `not_in([1,2,3], 4)` will return true. But you can't use `in` and `not in` operators on dataframe anyway